# Windows 8 replaces my Wifi drivers

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers

Recently "upgraded" my HP Probook 4330S to Windows 8 from 7.
Windows 8 came with its own drivers for the Wifi card (a Ralink one) pre-installed.

Now when I install the correct drivers (the correct drivers are the drivers from HP's webpage, I must use them as they are the only ones that work on my school's wifi.), it seems that Windows 8 replaces those after a while with its own.

Is there away to permanently remove all Wifi drivers, so I can then just install the one driver I want to keep?

Comment: You can use the device manager to delete device drivers.  Why are you against using the generic drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling automatic updates, and instead, making them selective. That way, you can choose to not install the wifi driver that you don't want from Windows while still getting the regular security updates.

Press the Windows key and type **update** to bring it up in the search bar. Open the Windows Update Settings, click on **Choose how updates get installed** and switch to **Download updates but let me choose whether to install them.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe I solved it. 
When it replaced the driver, I went into device manager and right clicked the Wifi card and hit "Roll back driver". Haven't had any issues since.